# protect folders via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to protect some folders from a normal user but i (from localhost or my IP address) m unable to see the folder structure...so i do this

write a `.htaccess` file in that folder(eg.project/cms/js) and write below code

```
# no nasty crackers in here!
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.1.7
```

but by using this prohibit to everyone( including me) to see that folder structure.....
how do i protect that folder from other users except myself?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the allow and deny the wrong way around:

```
order allow,deny
allow from 192.168.1.7
deny from all
```

which first processes all the allow statements and next the deny statements.

Comment: it does not work dude....still i can't enter that folder

`Access forbidden!` is coming

Comment: @Pekka yes sir. but i used 127.0.0.1 also

Comment: @I like PHP check my 2nd answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked, your above example works fine for me on my Apache 2.
Make sure your IP really is `192.168.1.7`. Note that if it's the local machine you're trying to access, your IP will be `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: i also use 127.0.0.1 but still `Access forbidden!` is coming on that folder
actually i hev aritten htaccess inside that folder, is that wrong??

Comment: i put .htaccess on 
`C:\xampp\htdocs\project\cms\includes`
and not working ...also i have restart xampp...

Comment: @I Like no need to restart XAMPP for htaccess files. You would have to check what client IP you have, something might be wrong there. You can find out using `phpinfo()`

Comment: `_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]=127.0.0.1` and
`_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] =127.0.0.1` is shown in phpinfo()

Comment: And you if use your above example and use `allow from 127.0.0.1` you're 100% sure it doesn't work?

Comment: @I like PHP and you are totally sure there is no other `.htaccess` file in one of the parent directories? Or a `deny from all` directive somewhere in the Apache config?

Comment: i cant't say sure about this..let me check.